# Is there a cleaner way to write this part of code, a lot of javascript if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a cleaner way to write this part of code?
I feel like there are too much else if statements
It can most likely be done using switch statement but how cleaner or more readable will it be?

```
if (inflationArray.every((x) => x.value.length == 0)) {
    alert("Every field is empty");
    return;
  } else if (
    inflationArray[0].value.length == 0 &&
    inflationArray[1].value.length != 0 &&
    inflationArray[2].value.length == 0
  ) {
    alert("You didn't type in any money value or inflation rate");
    return;
  } else if (
    inflationArray[0].value.length == 0 &&
    inflationArray[1].value.length == 0 &&
    inflationArray[2].value.length != 0
  ) {
    alert("You didn't type in any money value or years");
    return;
  } else if (
    inflationArray[0].value.length != 0 &&
    inflationArray[1].value.length == 0 &&
    inflationArray[2].value.length == 0
  ) {
    alert("You didn't type in any year or inflation rate");
    return;
  } else if (inflationArray[0].value.length == 0) {
    alert("You didn't type in any money value");
    return;
  } else if (inflationArray[1].value.length == 0) {
    alert("You didn't type in any year");
    return;
  } else if (inflationArray[2].value.length == 0) {
    alert("You didn't type any inflation rate");
    return;
  }
```

Comment: You could perhaps use a Switch with a bunch of cases

Comment: One if for every case, collect in a list and then concatenate failing cases

Comment: See [many more related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+can+I+reduce+ifs+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com).